# How to identify the reviews where the sentiment of review text does not match rating

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, data-science

can anyone help me with the problem, Im trying to build NLP model where i collect the user reviews and ratings of the app. There are times where user writes a good review but also give low rating. How do i identify those reviews.
CSV file contains user reviews, rating and name column

Answer (score 0):

I think more information is needed here to understand your question...

What will be the final aim of your NLP model? Do you want to build a sentiment classifier that distinguishes between positive and negative reviews?

> There are times where user writes a good review but also give low rating.

I assume that here what you mean is that the user gives a *positive* review but a low rating, right?

In that case what you could do is use a pre-trained sentiment classifier in order to get the predicted sentiment of each review. You could then compare that to the ratings you have on your CSV and pick out the ones that are very different.

However, sadly the best way to clean inconsistent data is often to do manual cleaning.... going through the reviews one by one and determine yourself if the rating makes sense given the review.

Another approach would be to ignore this inconsistent reviews altogether and hope they are so few they wont mess up with your model